# sed command to delete xml-element cantains part of string

Tags: xml, bash, sed

i need help with the sed command to delete some elements from a xml-file. i know that i can use saxon to do that job, but i think its not efficient.

The situation: 
I receive from an external script an array and for all fields in the array i want to use the sed command to check the xml-file if the field is contained in a specific element, if result get true i want to delete that element and the parent element with all childs.

The xml-file is as follow:

```
<league>
   <team>club1</team>
      <id>1001</id> 
      <position>12</position>
      <description>
         <comment>frist comment</comment>
         <logo>no logo available</logo>
         <path>/home/stack/overflow/id111-111-222-222</path>
      </description>
   </team> 
   <team>club2</team>
      <id>1002</id> 
      <position>42</position>
      <description>
         <comment>second comment</comment>
         <logo>logo available</logo>
         <path>/home/stack/overflow/id333-333-444-444</path>
      </description>
   </team>

   ...

   <team>clubn</team>
      <id>100n</id> 
      <position>n</position>
      <description>
         <comment>nth comment</comment>
         <logo>no logo available</logo>
         <path>/home/stack/overflow/id888-888-999-999</path>
      </description>
   </team>
```

Now for an array filed sed should check if the field is included in any path element. if its in any path then it should delete that element (path) with the parent and all other child.

for example the array filed [1]= 888-888-999-999. The result should view as follow:

```
<league>
   <team>club1</team>
      <id>1001</id> 
      <position>12</position>
      <description>
         <comment>frist comment</comment>
         <logo>no logo available</logo>
         <path>/home/stack/overflow/id111-111-222-222</path>
      </description>
   </team> 
   <team>club2</team>
      <id>1002</id> 
      <position>42</position>
      <description>
         <comment>second comment</comment>
         <logo>logo available</logo>
         <path>/home/stack/overflow/id333-333-444-444</path>
      </description>
   </team>

   ...

   <team>clubn</team>
      <id>100n</id> 
      <position>n</position>
   </team>
```

i hope anyone can understand me and my problem :)

greeds

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Comment: How can i delete a xml node with xmllint inplace?

Comment: if i use `grep -vq "888-888-999-999" file | sed -i '\|888-888-999-999|d' file` it will delete only the line where a matching will found but how can i delete the node below??

Answer (score 0):

This joins the `filed` array fields to form an *alternation*, and then lets `sed` collect the lines of the parent element and delete them if an array field is included in a path element:

```
IFS='|' regexp="${filed[*]}"
sed "/<description>/{:label;/<\/description>/!{N;blabel};
                     /<path>.*\(${regexp//|/\|}\).*<\/path>/d}"
```